# Voximplant: switching language in DialogFlow

Tags: voximplant

I have a DialogFlow integration working in my Voximplant application.
Now I add a language to dialogflow agent.
I didnt't find a way to dynamically switch language in this telephony integration.

Should I just send the user to select the language before integration start?
What's is the best approach here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can ask user to choose the language, for example, by pressing a key on their phone:

```
call.addEvetnListener(callEvents.ToneReceived, (e) => {
  let data = e.tone;
});
```

https://voximplant.com/docs/references/voxengine/callevents#tonereceived